# How to combine multiple arrays into single JSON object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json

I have three arrays:

```
c = ["1", "2", "3"]
d = [["x1","x2","x3"],["x4","x5","x6"], ["x7","x8","x9"]]
e = [["20","21","22"], ["23","24","25"], ["26","27","28"]]
```

And I want to merge them together in Ruby to get this JSON result:

```
[
 {"1":{ 
        "x1":"20",
        "x2":"21",
        "x3":"22"
      },
      { 
        "x4":"23",
        "x5":"24",
        "x6":"25"
      },
      { 
        "x7":"26",
        "x8":"27",
        "x9":"28"
      },
 }
]
```

Comment: What are `x1`, `x2`, `x3`? they seem like variables.  Do you want their names in output hash? That seems impossible to do.  May be you need to look at your problem differently

Comment: "I forget to surround them by quotes", then edit your question and fix them please. It's important that your examples and code be accurate. Please read "[mcve]".

Comment: What is the purpose of `"2"` and `"3"` in `c`? Are then insignificant/ignored? If they're significant then how are you expecting them to be used? Your selected answer doesn't match your desired output at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c = ["1", "2", "3"]
d = [['x1','x2','x3'],['x4','x5','x6'], ['x7','x8','x9']]
e = [[20,21,22], [23,24,25], [26,27,28]]

require 'json'

pairs = d.map { |a| a.map(&:to_sym) }.zip(e).map(&:transpose)
  #=> [[[:x1, 20], [:x2, 21], [:x3, 22]],
  #    [[:x4, 23], [:x5, 24], [:x6, 25]],
  #    [[:x7, 26], [:x8, 27], [:x9, 28]]]    
c.each_with_object({}) { |s,h| h[s] = pairs.shift.to_h }.to_json
  #=> "{\"1\":{\"x1\":20,\"x2\":21,\"x3\":22},\"2\":
       {\"x4\":23,\"x5\":24,\"x6\":25},\"3\":{\"x7\":26,\"x8\":27,\"x9\":28}}"
```

(I broke the JSON string to two lines to avoid the need for horizontal scrolling.)

Alternatively,

```
pairs = [d.map { |a| a.map(&:to_sym) }, e].transpose.map(&:transpose)
```